# Laravel - Get data by month

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to retrieve data by month of a given year.
I would like to do it in one query.

In my DB Schema I have two columns that store `month` and `year`.

I have tried:

```
Outgoings::where('year', 2017)->groupBy('month')->get();
```

But I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'gestionale.outgoings.id' which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `outgoings` where
>   `year` = 2017 group by `month`)

So the only thing that comes to my mind is a bit tricky, fetch all months and for each month query the db and get the sum of a value.

Something like:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
            $out = Outgoing::where('year', 2017)->where('month', $i)->get();
            // sum
        }
```

Any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrict mode is on by default in Laravel, this causes `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error. You can turn it off in `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    ....
    'strict' => false, // This is the option you need to change.
    'engine' => null,
],
```

If you don't want to use `groupBy()` and you want to iterate over the data, load data first and then work with a collection. For example, this code will create just one query (your code will create 12 queries):

```
$data = Outgoing::where('year', 2017)->get();
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    $out = $data->where('month', $i);
    // Do something with $out.
}
```

Comment: I have jsut tested it but there is a problem in the `for`. For some reason at each loop seems that the `where` do not work. 
I have `$out = $data->where('month', $i)->sum('price');` and return always `0` that is the sum of the first month. Maybe the where are linked?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi I don't see the data, so I just can't help you here.

Comment: I just have one entry with `price = 100` and `month=4`. If I manually set `4` it get the result, but in the for just set `0`. Maybe at every loop it add the where `->where('month', 1)->where('month', 2)` etc?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi no, collections do not add wheres if you're working with them as I've shown. Try to debug it. Look at `dd($data)` data, print out `$data->where('month', $i)->count();` etc

Comment: I added a listener to the query and after the first loop I get: `select count(*) as aggregate from `outgoings` where `year` = ? and `month` = ? and `month` = ? and `month` = ?` so it add wheres

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi then you're doing it wrong because the code I've shown is generating only one query with one where condition which is `year` related. I guess you forgot to add `get()` to the code which is before `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

To get earnings from database on monthly basis (Laravel):-

```
$getMonthlyReport = OrderMaster::select(DB::raw("sum(order_total_amt) as  earnings,date_format(order_date, '%Y-%m') as YearMonth"))
    ->groupBy('order_date')
    ->get();

$dataArr = [];
$labelArr = [];


foreach($getMonthlyReport as $report){
    array_push($dataArr, $report->earnings);
    array_push($labelArr, $report->YearMonth);
}
    return Response::json([
    'status' => true,
    'data' => $dataArr,
    'label' => $labelArr,
]);
```

}